# Display text programmatically for TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I am looking to set a text programmatically, but for some reason, when I am doing so, no text appears on the screen. I have attached my code below.

```
LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View lay = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fs, null);
    lsc = (TextView) lay.findViewById(R.id.fst);
    lsc.setText("XYZ performed on this day.");
```

Any ideas? "fs" is the xml file which has a textView component, whose id is "fst".

Comment: You are inflating a layout which has a TextView and setting some text to that TextView. But have you added that layout to an Activity or a Fragment?

Comment: Bob is right. You are editing some textview out of your activity or fragment. That's why it isn't seen.

Comment: Hi Bob, what do you mean when you say "have you added that layout to an Activity or a Fragment?"

Comment: Hi Bob, Still a little confused over what I would need to do to resolve the issue.

Comment: Randolph could you please provide the complete code